# How to make line breaks on an href variable?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, href

I can't make line breaks between each URL I get.
The urls are displayed in a row when I would like to have 1 url per line.

Could you help me with this problem?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep



driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.twitch.tv/directory/game/League%20of%20Legends/clips?range=7d")

sleep(3)
i = 1
while i <= 20:
    links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@data-a-target='preview-card-image-link']")
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);', links[len(links)-1])
    print("=> i :", i)
    i+=20
    sleep(1)

links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@data-a-target='preview-card-image-link']")
for link in links:
    print(link.get_attribute('href'))
    f = (link.get_attribute('href'))
    c = open('proxy_list.txt', 'a')
    c.write(f)
```

Comment: It is printing url in different lines.. your code

Comment: no the url's are displayed in a row and not as a list i wanted a list not a row of url's

Answer (score 0):

A few things...

Your first `while` loop only loops once... I'm not sure if that's intentional or not? You are setting `i` to 1 and looping until i > 20. After the first command, you increment `i` by 20 which means that it will fail the `while` condition and fall out. If that's what you intend, you can get rid of most of that code and just keep 2 lines. The first block then becomes

```
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@data-a-target='preview-card-image-link']")
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);', links[len(links)-1])
```

The second block of code is looping through the returned links, getting the href in each and then writing to file. Writing to disk is slow so you want to minimize that as much as possible. Since you aren't trying to write millions of lines at once, you can just build your final string containing the hrefs in the loop and then once the loop is done, write the string to file. That way you only write to disk once.

Adding the line break is as simple as appending "\n" (newline character) to the end of each href.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.twitch.tv/directory/game/League%20of%20Legends/clips?range=7d")

links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@data-a-target='preview-card-image-link']")
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);', links[len(links)-1])

list = ""
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@data-a-target='preview-card-image-link']")
for link in links:
    print(link.get_attribute('href'))
    list += link.get_attribute('href') + "\n"

c = open('proxy_list.txt', 'a')
c.write(list)
```